# Plot a RGB point on the imshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I need to represent a single RGB point in the imshow but I'm not getting it, can anyone help me?

**Dados de entrada**

```
R = 1.0
G = 0.7042952754521196
B = 0.019247748523127214
```

**Código**

```
x = np.array([R, G, B])
x.shape = ()
plt.imshow(x)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot a RGB color, you were doing it right:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
R = 1.0
G = 0.7042952754521196
B = 0.019247748523127214
plt.imshow([[(R, G, B)]])
```

[image: color plot]